# How to group the products to their respective category in cart page?

Tags: cart, magento-1

I want the cart page to be like the added products like apple, orange etc into fruits category and fish into fresh fish category. How can i group them accordingly in the cart page ? For example:

Cart page:-
Fruits -> apple, orange.

Fresh Fish-> Bangude (Medium) fish, Kolathuru.

Please help. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should modify the template `app/design/frontend/your-theme/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml`. In this template, there is a loop :

```
<tbody>
    <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
        <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</tbody>
```

The key point will be to know what type each `$_item` is.
For this, you may create an helper method `getItemFoodType()` which returns `fish`,`fruit` or `other`.

Once you know that, you should create 2 arrays, loop on `$_items` and add each `$_item` to the correct array. Then you will loop on these freshly created arrays :

```
<tbody>
    <?php 
        $_fishes = array();
        $_fruits = array();
        $_others = array();
    ?>
    <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
        <?php 
           if(Mage::helper('your-helper')->getItemFoodType($_item)=='fish'){
                $_fishes[] = $_item;
           }
           elseif(Mage::helper('your-helper')->getItemFoodType($_item)=='fruit'){
               $_fruits[] = $_item;
           }
           else{
              $_others[] = $_item;
           }

        ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    <?php foreach($_fishes as $_fish): ?>
           <!-- you can add a <div class="fishes"> if you want some custom design-->
           <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_fish) ?>
           <!-- </div> -->
    <?php endforeach ?>
    <?php foreach($_fruits as $_fruit): ?>
           <!-- you can add a <div class="fruits"> if you want some custom design-->
           <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_fruit) ?>
           <!-- </div> -->
    <?php endforeach ?>
    <?php foreach($_others as $_other): ?>
           <!-- you can add a <div class="others"> if you want some custom design-->
           <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_other) ?>
           <!-- </div> -->
    <?php endforeach ?>
</tbody>
```

Concerning the `getItemFoodType()` method, there is different way to do but I will summarize below the two I'm thinking about :

```
public function getItemFoodType($item){
   $product = $item->getProduct();
   // First Option
   // Here you can get categories of the $product and decide which are fruits, which are fishes and wich are others;
   //I let you search how to retrieve all the categories of a product 
   (hint : see the Link 1 below).


   // Second Option
   // An other way to do is to create a product attribute `food_type` (or what ever is explicit for you). 
   //You will have to assign the value (fish,fruit, etc) of this attribute to each product
   // Then you can know the type of your product with $product->getFoodType() 
   }
```

Link 1 : [How to get categories of a product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009861/how-do-i-get-categories-for-a-product-in-magento)

Comment: Thank you., I appreciate your answer. But I have the link 1 code in app/design/frontend/your-theme/default/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml. So Where do I add getItemFoodType($item) in my code ?

Comment: Well, you should create an helper in your own module. Then you can call your method with `Mage::helper('your-helper')->getItemFoodType($_item)`.